# Did Groot's memory survive?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, groot

In the end of *Marvel's Guardians of the Galaxy*, Rocket planted a splinter of Groot and baby Groot is growing already and he'll appear in upcoming *Marvel's Guardians of the Galaxy vol. 2*.

[image: Dancing Groot gif]

I wonder whether his memories survived. I mean, can he recall the events prior to his (temporary) death on Nova, maybe after he is old enough to stop being a *baby*? Anything even from the comics?

Comment: Sounds like possible future works to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it conflicts with our "Future Works" policy.

Comment: @Adamant - Precisely so. Impossible to answer now but trivially simple to answer in a few weeks.

Comment: Not future works. James Gunn [answered this last year](http://screenrant.com/guardians-of-galaxy-2-baby-groot-memories/)

Comment: Can I VTC the Future Works Policy itself?  I'm tired of pointing out to people that sometimes an answer exists, as it does here.   What we should be concentrating on, is that the ***answers*** need to be evidence-based, not speculative.   The questions themselves are not a problem.   The entire policy is ill-conceived.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### TL;DR: No, Groot's memories did not survive.

This is because the Groot of *Guardians of the Galaxy Volume 2* is not the same Groot as the one in *Guardians of the Galaxy Volume 1*.

In July 2016, [producer Kevin Feige previously said that Groot *would* retain his memories](http://collider.com/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2-trailer-baby-groot-kevin-feige)

> He remembers. He’s not mentally a baby, he is still Groot… I sort of equate it to Spock circa the end of Search for Spock and The Voyage Home.

However, in September of the same year, [director James Gunn flipped on that](http://screencrush.com/gunn-guardians-baby-groot-details/) during a Facebook Q&A.

> - *Is baby Groot the same as Groot, or Groot’s son?*
>
> It’s complicated.
>
> - *Does he have Groot’s memories?*
>
> **No.**

In February 2017, [Gunn restated this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/830867190173749248).

When asked specifically about Groot having his memories, he replied,

> No. He has no memories of adult Groot.

[image: No memories for Groot]

Additionally, back in October 2016, [Vin Diesel all but said that Groot would not have his memories](http://collider.com/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2-baby-groot-vin-diesel/), explaining that he has to "start all over" and re-learn everything.

> “Yeah, there is a difference. He couldn’t be more naive as Baby Groot. I always think of the Groot that we saw on the first Guardians as a college-level Groot, so he’s not fully grown yet, but he’s a man. And once he sacrifices himself at the end of the movie, now he has to start all over, so to speak, but we’re gonna see this goofy, adorable, baby Groot thing running around the screen and just learning as he goes.”

### So why no memories?

On May 14, 2017, James Gunn did a [Facebook Q&A](https://www.facebook.com/jgunn/videos/10154241332796157/). Someone asked about Groot. It's possible that Gunn was just being coy, but he casts doubt on whether or not Groot from *Guardians 2* is the same Groot as the one in *Guardians 1*.

> Colby Helton · 2:22 You mentioned Baby Groot doesn't retain memories from the first film, but what makes Groot the same Groot? What's his connection to GotG? Does he retain some emotional essence or is her just a baby?
>   James Gunn · Who said he was the same Groot?

[image: i am groot-2]
(*[source](https://www.facebook.com/jgunn/videos/10154241332796157/?comment_id=597108930496318&reply_comment_id=479194369138944&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D)*)

On February 27, 2018, James Gunn finally put the issue to rest declaring that [the Groot of *Volume 2* is the son of Groot from *Volume 1*](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/968576621220331520)

> First Groot is dead. Baby Groot is his son.

[image: Ok, but who is Baby Groot's mama?].

Comment: If you'd like a more solid answer to this, James Gunn quite recently confirmed on Twitter that Baby Groot is not the same Groot as the Groot we followed in _Guardians of the Galaxy_. Canonically, Baby Groot is Groot's offspring. https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/913469630399655937

Comment: These tweets could easily be retconned by future writers though.

Comment: Anything in any franchise can be retconned by future/later writers. Until that happens, this word of god is the canonical answer.